# Cant use Animations Angular 2

Tags: angular, animation, import, runtime-error

I want to use Animations in my Angular 2 App.
I already importet "BrowserAnimationsModule" to my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';
import { routes } from './app.router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { WinPageComponent } from './win-page/win-page.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    QuizShowStatusComponent,
    EntrancePageComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MainQuizComponent,
    WinPageComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    MainQuizComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routes,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule

  ],
  providers: [SharedService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

That is an excerpt of the component.ts that uses the animation:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-quiz',
  templateUrl: './main-quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-quiz.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class MainQuizComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService, private router: Router){
    this._sharedService = _sharedService;
  }
```

And that is an excerpt of the component.html

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <button type="button" [@answerPanel]='stateButton1' class="btn btn-answer" id="answerButton1" (click)='checkQuestion($event)'>{{currentAnswer1}}</button>
          </div>

</div>
```

But it gives me the error 
"Found the synthetic property @answerPanel. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application."

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Just checking the basics: did you also install and save `@angular/animations` to your project?

Comment: If i can use trigger, state, style and so on it needs to be installed doesnt it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Thanks for providing the additional info. I don't see animations configured for the component. Is it missing from your sample code? (Example below)

```
@Component(
template: ` // template here`,
styleUrls: [ // styles here ],
animations: [
    trigger('answerPanel', [
      state('inactive', style({
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        transform: 'scale(1)'
      })),
      state('active',   style({
        backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
        transform: 'scale(1.1)'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
...
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/animations

---

I'm assuming you've upgraded to Angular 4 since you're using BrowserAnimationsModule. Note the last line: the animation imports from `@angular/core` are deprecated and should be imported from `@angular/animations`.

From [4.0.0-rc1 change log](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#installing-rc1):

> If you rely on Animations you’ll also need to install the animations package `@angular/animations` and import the new `BrowserAnimationsModule` from `@angular/platform-browser/animations` in your root NgModule. Without this, your code will compile and run, but animations won’t activate. Imports from `@angular/core` were deprecated, use imports from the new package `import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';`.

Comment: Do you have a plunker to show what's wrong? Or could you edit your post to show the component class that's trying to use animations?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `animations` block in the component decorator?

Comment: Oh my god...I was trying to solve that problem so much so that I totally forgot to add the animation itself...But it's a little bit confusing that there isn't another error message for that error...But thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you step through your problem to its solution. Best wishes--have fun animating! :D